Does $M_N= \{\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sigma(2n-1)^{\sigma(2n)}\ |\ \sigma\in S_{2N}\}$ always contain a perfect square?
Let $M_N= \{\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sigma(2n-1)^{\sigma(2n)}\ |\ \sigma \in S_{2N}\}$. ($S_n$ denotes the group of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3,..., n\}$). So as an example $6^2+3^4+5^1=122$ would be a member of $M_3$. It seems to me that for all values of $N$, $M_N$ will always contain a perfect square. Here is the list of perfect squares in $M_1,...,M_5$ respectively:
$$1$$
$$9$$
$$1089$$
$$1225, 1369, 11881, 73441$$
$$25921, 31684, 41616, 44100, 122500, 125316, 380689, 534361, 538756, 1036324, 1056784, 1690000, 100280196$$
I've verified the existence of a perfect square in $M_N$ for $N≤9$:
$$1300^2 = 10^4+2^5+9^1+6^8+7^3$$
$$1474^2 = 8^7+12^3+11^4+6^1+9^5+10^2$$
$$6283^2 = 13^1+6^8+5^9+10^4+12^7+14^2+11^3$$
$$3168697^2= 14^1+6^{12}+10^{13}+11^7+2^8+16^5+3^4+15^9$$
$$2975390^2= 4^{16}+18^9+15^{11}+10^3+6^5+14^7+13^1+12^8+2^{17}$$
Can anybody prove/disprove the claim that $M_N$ always contains a perfect square? (P.S. I'm unsure on which tags are appropriate for this question)

I would add the elementary-number-theory tag.

What is $S_{2N}?$

@ThomasAndrews  the group of all permutations of {1, 2, 3, ... 2N}

Heuristically, we'd expect it true.The value of this sum is bounded above by $M=(2N)^{2N}$ and there are $(2N)^N,$ perfect squares less than that. If we picked at random numbers from $1$ to $M,$ we'd lexpect to get a perfect square by pick $(2N)^N.$ Now, $(2N)!>(2N/e)^{2N}=(2N)^N\cdot (2N/e^2)^{N}.$  So when $N$ is large, this value is much more than the expected number of trials expected to pick a perfect square. Even when $N=3,$ $6!=720$ and $(2N)^N=216.$ So we'd expect to find three squares in that many trials.

(The reason I jumped to heuristics immediately is that I can't see any specific algebraic properties here of numbers of this form.)

My estimates there are very crude, and it seems to overestimate the chances - maybe my upper bound is off, or adding a lower bound will make it better (most of the squares are small.) But I think heuristically this is very likely to be true, although I see no obvious way to prove it.

@ThomasAndrews The expected number of distinct numbers in the $M_N$ is approximately $\frac{(2N)!}{N!}$ not $(2N)!$...

Ah, of course! @BryleMorga
